# Restrict only one type of object in Generic List

Tags: java, generics

```java
class Polygon {

}

class Rectangle extends Polygon {

}

class Square extends Rectangle {

}

class Point extends Square {

}
```

I have this class hierarchy and I want to make a `List` that accepts **only one type** of the above objects.

`List<Polygon> list = new ArrayList<>();` - would accept any of the above classes `Polygon`, `Rectangle`, `Square` or `Point`.

How do I restrict that list to hold only one type of object at any given time?
If the list is storing `Polygon`, then it should only be able to store objects of `Polygon` and not any of its sub-classes.

Comment: That's a violation of OOP fundamentals. A `Rectangle` *is* a `Polygon`. If you want them to be treated as distinct types, they shouldn't be subclasses.

Comment: You could write your own list type and check the runtime type of each element as you add it. With a standard list you can always add a Rectangle to a List<Polygon>.

Comment: Creating a custom list to violate principles of inheritance is HUGE hack and should be avoided at all costs. But, if you want to experiment, you will need to create a custom list and in the `add` method, you will need to check that a particular object is of a specific class instance by calling `obj.getClass().isAssignableFrom(class)`, where `class` will be some reference to a class' class (i.e. `Polygon.class`). This easier said than done, but you are welcome to try.

Comment: @khelwood, @hfontanez I ended up creating a custom class that extends `ArrayList` and overrides the `add()` with a type check. Thank you!

Comment: @hfontanez `obj.getClass().isAssignableFrom(clazz)` needlessly whitelists superclasses, like `Object` (though that would be prevented by safe compile-time usage). Just check `obj.getClass() == clazz`.

Comment: @shmosel didn't think about that. I guess that works too. At least you understand where I was coming from. A dude here posted that, to solve this issue you needed to add yet another class to the hierarchy. My main point was to avoid the mistake that many inexperienced devs make by using `instanceof` operator.

Comment: @saintlyzero I am glad that you were able to create a solution on your own (although I still think you should've avoided this altogether) without asking people to code it for you. That's what matters in the end. Congratulations!